# Falied to load resource files of Oracle APEX plugin

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-18c

I've installed a plugin in APEX, but when I've tried to use it on a page, I've got some nasty errors and page not working properly.

The files are present in the plugin settings:

[image: files are present]

But, as you can see below, they are not being loaded for some reason. I get 404 errors instead.

[image: but errors are too]
I have ORDS running and APEX 19 installed on DB 19c XE.

What could be causing this? Wrong ORDS configuration maybe? How to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After APEX upgrade from one version to another you should recompile `i.war` by running `java -jar ords.war validate --database apex`. `java -jar ords.war static` could also be useful.

For debug it is convinient to edit ORDS config file `defaults.xml` with these strings:

```
<entry key="debug.debugger">true</entry>
<entry key="debug.printDebugToScreen">true</entry>
```

Don't forget to set them `false` on production.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.  I checked the APEX and ORDS accounts, their passwords had expired.  Once I fixed that, the problem was solved.